# Instantiate interface in java ( Android )

Tags: java, android, interface

[am i instantiating a interface here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgP5g.png)

Interfaces should be like abstract classes right?

Note: this project compiles, run and works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're creating an anonymous class that implements that interface, and instantiating that. The same would be true if it were an abstract class instead of an interface.

What you're doing is similar to creating an inner class and instantiating that.

```
public class MoviePresenter {
    public interface MovieReady {
        void onMoviesReady();
    }

    //...

    public MoviePresenter(Context mContext, RecyclerView movieRecycler) {
        mr = new MovieReadyImpl();
        //...
    }

    //...

    public class MovieReadyImpl implements MovieReady { //this is the equivalent to what you're doing. It just has a proper class name
         @Override
         public void onMoviesReady() {
             InitRecyclerView();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it better to create a class to instatiate ir, or implement it in the main class?

Comment: It's mostly a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an anonymous class that implements that interface. Notice how you're providing the implementation of `onMoviesReady()` in the `MoviePresenter`.

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) some additional reading material on that.